# show all files under a dirctory

Tags: file, directory, operating-system

```
import os


def findFiles(root_dir="C:/Users/15025/Desktop/books/", res=None):
    if not res:
        res = []
    for f in os.listdir(root_dir):
        f_path = os.path.join(root_dir, f)
        if os.path.isfile(f_path):
            res.append(f_path)
        elif os.path.isdir(f_path):
            findFiles(f_path, res)
    
    return res


result = findFiles()
print(result)
```

I find some problems here, if I have a file under `"C:/Users/15025/Desktop/books/"` directory, like `deepLearning`, and in this `deepLearning` file I have a document named `debug.py`. But when I run this program, the `print(result)`shows nothing, it is strange. Could someone tell me why? I think it is because the program will be called twice. But what is the reason in detail?

The figure of my directory and the running result could seen below:
[image: my directory]

[image: running result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WTF, I feel I always answer my own question, finally, I find that I should change `findFiles(f_path, res)` to `res = findFiles(f_path, res)`, and then everything is fine.